# Pasting an image on another image

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to paste 4 images with the size of: 422x223 to a image that is 844x446.
I saw that `img.paste` takes 2 arguments: image and box.

This is what I tried:

```
from PIL import Image
with Image.open(r"ALLPARTS.png") as end:
    with Image.open(r"TOPLEFT.png") as img:
        end.paste(img,(0,0))
    with Image.open(r"BOTTOMLEFT.png") as img:
        end.paste(img,(0,223,422,0))
    with Image.open(r"BOTTOMRIGHT.png") as img:
        end.paste(img,(422,223,0,0))
    with Image.open(r"TOPRIGHT.png") as img:
        end.paste(img,(422,0,0,223))
    end.save(r"ALLPARTS.png")
```

For `TOPLEFT.png` it does work but not for the rest.
I am getting the error:

```
self.im.paste(im, box)

ValueError: images do not match
```

and I did not understand why.I thought I understood how the "box" works but apparently I did not.
So can you also explain how it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That box is (x0, y0, x1, y1) where Point 0 is upper left and Point 1 is lower down corner:

```
from PIL import Image
with Image.open(r"ALLPARTS.png") as end:
    with Image.open(r"TOPLEFT.png") as img:
        end.paste(img,(0,0))
    with Image.open(r"BOTTOMLEFT.png") as img:
        end.paste(img,(0,223,422,446))
    with Image.open(r"BOTTOMRIGHT.png") as img:
        end.paste(img,(422,223,844,446))
    with Image.open(r"TOPRIGHT.png") as img:
        end.paste(img,(422,0,422,223))
    end.save(r"ALLPARTS.png")
```

Or with provided two-tuple (just upper-left corner point):

```
from PIL import Image
with Image.open(r"ALLPARTS.png") as end:
    with Image.open(r"TOPLEFT.png") as img:
        end.paste(img,(0,0))
    with Image.open(r"BOTTOMLEFT.png") as img:
        end.paste(img,(0,223))
    with Image.open(r"BOTTOMRIGHT.png") as img:
        end.paste(img,(422,223))
    with Image.open(r"TOPRIGHT.png") as img:
        end.paste(img,(422,0))
    end.save(r"ALLPARTS.png")
```

Comment: It still shows the error though,any idea why?Edit:one of the images wasn't in the same size as the others that's probably the cause of the error.

Comment: I still get the error for the last one though,and it is in a right size.

Comment: Really don't know, try with the edited answer with just the upper left point provided.

Answer (score 0):

The 4-tuple you pass as a box should match the size of the image being pasted, and takes the form `(left, top, right, bottom)`.

I think the coordinates you are using are wrong because of this.

Alternatively, you can just pass a 2-tuple, giving the top-left coordinate, like you do in the first example.

Comment: If the size of the image is 422x223 what is the max(left,top,right,bottom) that I can pass then?

Comment: The maximum would be a box of that size that does not go outside the bounds of the bottom image. So for example, the maximum would be the size of the original image: `(0, 223, 422, 0)